# How to use Illustrator AI file to design a Wordpress website

Tags: svg

I am very new to Wordpress. I have an AI file and I am supposed to build a website out of it. Just have some difficulties in doing that. I select some slices in Adobe Illustrator and export them into a SVG file but it is like 1 or 2 megabyte. So, That's a bit too much for web.

Also, What should I do to the texts that are placed besides the slices? When I export them they aren't shown properly. I can edit the svg file code manually and correct the texts, But their place isn't correct too.

[image]

The least thing I want to know is that am I doing something totally wrong or just partly wrong? I mean, Is this the conventional way? An actual web designer/developer selects some slices in Illustrator and export them as SVG files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can save for web for each element and upload it by using DIVI Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting a sliced illustrator file is not the way to go to set up a WordPress website. This just exports a svg file or a html file with some images, but you wont be able to import that into a working theme or wp template.

The thing you want to do is create a custom theme, or create a layout using some page builder that would allow you to create a page like the above.

If you want to create a custom theme, you should start creating a html file with your layout. My advise would be to create a static html with css and images, and convert that into a working theme.

Some good starting points for developing themes can be found on wordpress.org:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Or, if you prefer a page builder you could check out some of them:
https://elementor.com/
https://www.wpbeaverbuilder.com/
https://www.elegantthemes.com/

Comment: Thanks. This is not a big website. Just a few pages. I have Avada theme and I can use it. So I have to use its layout/page builder. But how actually I should do it? I mean what should I do in Illustrator? How to get that things in the AI file? You said you shouldn't export slices, Then how?

Comment: You only export images from illustrator, for example all the little teeth-icons or the device in your header. Maybe also the blue background in your header, and the light blue things in the background of the content. Sp you can upload and use these images later on the website. You cant import an illustrator file in your builder, you need to rebuild your layout using your theme Avada or another pagebuilder. So basicly you start more or less from scratch.